# generate group id based on data matched in different columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to generate group_id as shown in the image for the matched record based on previous last name.

Create and insert scripts :

```
create table t2 (
id number,
last_name varchar2(200),
previous_last_name varchar2(200),
group_id number
);

Insert into T2 (ID,LAST_NAME,PREVIOUS_LAST_NAME) values (1,'Scott',null);
Insert into T2 (ID,LAST_NAME,PREVIOUS_LAST_NAME) values (2,'Stephen',null);
Insert into T2 (ID,LAST_NAME,PREVIOUS_LAST_NAME) values (3,'Baker',null);
Insert into T2 (ID,LAST_NAME,PREVIOUS_LAST_NAME) values (4,'Smith','Baker');
Insert into T2 (ID,LAST_NAME,PREVIOUS_LAST_NAME) values (5,'John','Miller');
Insert into T2 (ID,LAST_NAME,PREVIOUS_LAST_NAME) values (6,'Miller',null);
```

-- match the records based on last_name and previous_last_name

```
select * from t2 a,t2 b  where a.last_name=b.previous_last_name;
```

-- results

```
ID|LAST_NAME|PREVIOUS_LAST_NAME|GROUP_ID|ID_1|LAST_NAME_1|PREVIOUS_LAST_NAME_1|GROUP_ID_1
3|Baker     |                  |        |4   |Smith      |Baker               |
6|Miller    |                  |        |5   |John       |Miller              |
```

/* need a query to update the group_id to get the below results */

```
select * from t2;

ID|LAST_NAME|PREVIOUS_LAST_NAME|GROUP_ID
1|Scott     |                  |
2|Stephen   |                  |
3|Baker     |                  |1
4|Smith     |Baker             |1
5|John      |Miller            |2
6|Miller    |                  |2
```

I tried update the group_id using merge statement but haven't got the desired results. The group_id doesn't need to be a number but a unique value (e.g. SYS_GUID())

below 2 step merge worked and gave the results but looking for better way to achieve this

```
MERGE INTO T2 XX
   USING (select previous_last_name, SYS_GUID() as cluster_id from T2) S
   ON (XX.last_name = S.previous_last_name)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET XX.group_id = S.cluster_id;
   
MERGE INTO T2 XX
   USING (select last_name, group_id as cluster_id from T2) S
   ON (XX.previous_last_name = S.last_name)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET XX.group_id = S.cluster_id;
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, don't add images to show data models or code. What is the query you are running ? what is the expected output ?

Comment: It is rather unclear, which logic you want. You should separate the sample data and the desired results in two different tables (and provide them as tabular text rather than images). You are also supposed to show what you have tried to solve the problem by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I used the ROWNUM function to achieve your result. It's working for me. SQL's mentioned below.

```sql
SELECT a.last_name, ROWNUM GROUP_ID
  FROM t2 a, t2 b
WHERE a.last_name = b.previous_last_name;

UPDATE t2
   SET t2.GROUP_ID =
           (SELECT c.GROUP_ID
              FROM (SELECT a.last_name, ROWNUM GROUP_ID
                      FROM t2 a, t2 b
                     WHERE a.last_name = b.previous_last_name) c
             WHERE NVL (t2.previous_last_name, t2.last_name) = c.last_name);
             
select * from t2;
```

[Click here to view the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hN9qW.png)